# JavaScript/jQuery - onhashchange event workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fragment-identifier, hashchange

Until all browsers support the onhashchange event what is the best workaround for this?

Is there something for this in jQuery? or as a plug-in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Back Button/Hash Change in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not but worth a try:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-hashchange-plugin

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is.

Check out this jQuery plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 6):

```
var lastHash = "";

window.onload=function()
{   
 hashChangeEventListener = setInterval("hashChangeEventHandler()", 50);
}

function hashChangeEventHandler()
{
    var newHash = location.hash.split('#')[1];

    if(newHash != lastHash)
    {
        lastHash = newHash;
        //Do stuff!
    }
}
```

Works fine for me across all tested (damn near all) platforms.

Answer (score 1):

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Another library that abstracts url management is [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an iframe cross domain solution this seems to be the most robust out there:
http://easyxdm.net/wp/
http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

I haven't tried it though and it seems like it could be a bit difficult to implement and might not work in all situations.