# Detect URL change in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just tried this code and it works well to detect URL,

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("#2") > -1) {
       alert("your on slide 2");
    } }); </script>
```

But not for my case.

In fact, I want to put this in a slideshow which works like this :
`www.slideshow.com/#1, www.slideshow.com/#2... etc`

So this code run if I refresh the `slide 2`, but not if I acces to this slide by clicking on the `Next Slide` Button on the first slide. I hope you understand my problem and help me find a solution

Thank you very much !

Comment: you may finding pjax http://pjax.heroku.com/

Answer (score 3):

window.location.hash and onhashchange event are what you are looking for.

http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2008/11/21/javascript-get-window-hashanchor-get-link-target/

[JavaScript/jQuery - onhashchange event workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783760/javascript-jquery-onhashchange-event-workaround)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [pushState API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

You can then listen to the [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate) to see when the user navigates.

And if you want to support browsers that don't support this, you'll probably need a pushState [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)