# Twitter bootstrap accordion wizard scrolls to the top of the page every time. how can i stop that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The page in question:

http://www.maidsinmemphis.com/index.php?id=6

How can I stop it from scrolling to the accordion locations and just scroll to the top of the page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the docs on https://github.com/sathomas/acc-wizard you will find you can call a function on onNext (also used) in your example code. This on next event is not called when you click / open an accordion tab unfortunately.
But the OnNext and tab click both cause a url hash change. You can use this hash change to trigger the scroll to top of the page.

On [JavaScript/jQuery - onhashchange event workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783760/javascript-jquery-onhashchange-event-workaround) you will find some functions for the onhashchange-event. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-top/ gives a scroll top top function. Together makes:

```
var lastHash = "";

window.onload=function()
{   
 hashChangeEventListener = setInterval("hashChangeEventHandler()", 50);
}

function hashChangeEventHandler()
{
    var newHash = location.hash.split('#')[1];

    if(newHash != lastHash)
    {
        lastHash = newHash;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');

    }
}
```