# Using the Back Button with Jquery Ajax .Load

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, back

I am using jQuerys .load to Ajax in new content, but this means my back button in my browser is disabled. Is there a way to get the back button to work and show the content that was previously loaded?

This is the code I am using to load the div with new ajax content:

```
$(".itm1 a").click(function(evt) {
     var page = $(this).attr('href');
     $("#page1").load(page, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn("slow"); 
     });
     evt.preventDefault();
  });
```

If you need anymore explanation of how I am doing this let me know! PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: You could utilize `window.hash` and `window.onhashchange`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Back Button/Hash Change in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url)

Comment: I am stumped on how to implement this, could someone write me a snippet? If you would be so kind....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
function load(page) {
    window.location.hash = page;
}
```

This can be used to add the hash to the page you are loading.

And on loading you check if hash exists and load the page:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash.length > 1) {
        page = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
        load(page);
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

I was a bit quick when reading your question.. 
For the best performance and compatibily I would recommend you to try the following plugin: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange