# Ajax .load refresh/back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm opening part of my pages in div with Ajax. But when i refresh or hit the back button it just doesnt do what it should. 
I read and tried a lot to get this to work but it just dont want to work.
I'm at a point that when i hit the the refresh or back button my address bar give the right page, but my div doenst change (e.g. address bar says: /projects.php but the page/div is still on index.php)

I just want to use the back/forward buttons and when i refresh the page it has to stay at the same page and dont go back to the first mainpage.

Here is my code, hope someone have a solution:

Html - my menu

```
<div id="buttons">
<a class="menu" id="page1" href="#Home">Home</a><span>|</span>
<a class="menu" id="page2" href="#Projects">Projects</a><span>|</span>
<a class="menu" id="page3" href="#About">About</a><span>|</span>
<a class="menu" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

.load part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#page1").click(function(){
$('#content').load('index.php #content');
});

$("#page2").click(function(){
$('#content').load('projecten.php #content');
});

$("#page3").click(function(){
$('#content').load('overons.php #content');
});
});
```

.haschange part

```
    $(function(){

  // These two properties, set after jQuery and the hashchange event plugin are
  // loaded, only need to be used when document.domain is set (to fix the "access
  // denied" error in IE6/7).
  $.fn.hashchange.src = '../../document-domain.html'; //--- I still dont know what to do with this, but i guess its only for IE6/7 ---//
  $.fn.hashchange.domain = document.domain;

  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
  // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;

    // Set the page title based on the hash.
    document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';

    // Iterate over all nav links, setting the "selected" class as-appropriate.
    $('#buttons a').each(function(){
      var that = $(this);
      that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
    });
  })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).hashchange();

});
```

Comment: It is my opinion, that your question would use a little work reducing it to the bare essentials: What is the smallest example that displays the problem you are experiencing? Create e.g. a JSFiddle with a working example of your problem. You could use [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barzik/QZ3ff/) as a starting point and expand from there.

Who knows, you may find the solution along the way! Yes, creating e.g. a JSFiddle is quite a bit of work. But it clarifies the problem and question (also for you!) and makes it much easier to answer when we can see and play with a working problem.

Comment: Thats no option sorry. I tried it but jsfiddle and codepen dont change the addressbar. A good example from what i want is this website (http://crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html#studio). When you play with the left menu and refresh/use back button, it just acts like it should. In my case only the hashtag link in the addressbar changes, but the content stays where it is. So when im on /#about and i go back the page stays at the #about content but in the addressbar it says /#index.

Comment: Anyone with a solution?

Comment: My back button is enabled and clickable, so when i hit the back button everything is OK except that my page/content doesnt go back.This is a must imo.

Answer (score 1):

When you only change the fragment the page doesn't reload or anything.

This is the thing with SPA (Single Page Applications) - they don't reload the page. Which is why e.g. Gmail maintains the page state even though the URL after the `#` (aka *fragment*) changes. Open a different folder and/or email and see that the URL fragment changes.

You'll need to listen to those events and do actions similar to your `$('#pageN').click()` handlers yourself. Also do something similar if a user opens http://yourserver/#page2 directly. And think about SEO if that is applicable to you.

See a similar question: [javascript - Detecting Back Button/Hash Change in URL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172957/detecting-back-button-hash-change-in-url) (do try to use the HTML5 API [if you can](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)),

See e.g. [Intelligent State Handling · browserstate/history.js Wiki](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) for some background info.

Or create completely separate pages where the URL path (before the `#` changes). Like in the good old days.

Comment: "Or create completely separate pages where the URL path (before the # changes). Like in the good old days" this sounds interesting, can you be more specific about this? I also tried html5 history api but it doesnt react on refresh, so most methods are just right not how it should be. I have complete separate pages so from there a solution would be nice so the whole page doesnt refresh after click a link. It would be no problem when i didnt use a carousel, but i do unfortunately.